# Upgrading kernel from 5.4.0-56-generic to 5.4.0-58-generic breaks NVIDIA driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, kernel, graphics

I'm on ubuntu 20.04 and had been using the Linux kernels 5.4.0-54-generic and then 5.4.0-56-generic for a while. Today I ran `apt upgrade` and it pulled in a new kernel, 5.4.0-58-generic. After rebooting, my NVIDIA driver appears to no longer work. My screen resolution is 1024x768 and cannot be changed. If I boot back into 5.4.0-56-generic, everything works fine.

**How do I get the NVIDIA driver to work properly with this new kernel?**

`nvidia-smi` tells me:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.32.00    Driver Version: 455.32.00    CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Graphics Device     Off  | 00000000:0A:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   44C    P8     8W / 220W |    178MiB /  7979MiB |      4%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1185      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 41MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2077      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 91MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2199      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               32MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What is the output of `dkms status`?  Please add that to your question.

Comment: Check how your Nvidia 455 has been installed.  The standard repos are offering 455.38, not the 455.32.0 you are showing.

Comment: @ubfan1 it was installed using the cuda runfile

Comment: @Terrance `dkms status` outputs nothing

Comment: It's better to use the drivers from the graphics-drivers PPA as it will install the dkms driver that gets carried over when you get kernel updates.  The driver that comes with the run file does not and you will have to reinstall the driver everytime you get a kernel update.

Comment: Thanks @Terrance. I have reinstalled the drivers using that PPA. I'll see what happens next time I get a kernel update.

Comment: I have also an update to 5.4.0-60. The kernel driver is not working at all.
dkms status
nvidia, 460.32.03, 5.4.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 460.32.03, 5.8.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 460.32.03, 5.8.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed